# Why is "i & (i ^ (i - 1))" equivalent to "i & (-i)"

Tags: bit-manipulation

I had this in part of the code. Could anyone explain how `i & (i ^ (i - 1))` could be reduced to `i & (-i)`?

Comment: Because of [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).

Comment: Is it? Let `i = 1`. Then `i ^ (i-1) = 1 ^ (1-1) = 1 ^ 0 = 1` and this does not equal to `-i = -1`

Comment: What's your language? Does `^` mean "to the power of" (`2 ^ 3 = 2 * 2 * 2 = 8`) or "xor" (`2 ^ 3 = 10b ^ 11b = 01b = 1`)?

Comment: @Kousha hum, you're right. Retracted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`i ^ (i - 1)` makes **all bits** after the *last 1 bit* of i becomes 1.

For example if `i` has a binary representation as `abc...de10...0` then `i - 1` will be `abc...de01...1` in binary (See [Why does (x-1) toggle all the bits from the rightmost set bit of x?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50869508/995714)). The part before the last 1 bit is not changed when subtracting 1 from i, so `xor`ing with each other returns 0 in that part, while the remaining will be 1 because of the difference in `i` and `i - 1`. After that `i & (i ^ (i - 1))` will get the last 1 bit of i

`-i` will inverse all bits up to the last 1 bit of i because in two's complement `-i == ~i + 1`, and `i & (-i)` results the same like the above

For example:

```
      20 = 0001 0100
      19 = 0001 0011
 20 ^ 19 = 0000 0111 = 7
 20 & 7  = 0000 0100

     -20 = 1110 1100
20 & -20 = 0000 0100
```

See also

- [Why n bitwise and -n always return the right most bit (last bit)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54375295/995714)
- [What does (number & -number) mean in bit programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35861228/995714)