# Why does (x-1) toggle all the bits from the rightmost set bit of x?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit

Why does this property hold true?

> say the kth bit from right side is the first set bit in number 'x'.
>   (x-1) will toggle every bit upto kth bit from right side.

I can verify this property by writing the bit sequence for the numbers but I don't understand as to why this property is true? Can anyone help me with a simple proof or intuition as to why this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do a hand subtraction

```
  xxx100...00
- xxx000...01
─────────────
  xxx011...11
```

`x` represents bits that we don't care

Starting from the right, `10 - 1 = 1`, borrowing 1 from the next column

Then the next one is `0 - 0`, minus the borrow, which also results in `0 - 1 = 1` borrows 1. This sequence continues until the bit in subtrahend is 1, now we have `1 - 0 - borrow = 1 - 1 = 0`

As the result, all the bits up to the rightmost set bit will be inverted

Answer (score 2):

It's the same reason if you do (x-1) where x is a base 10 integers all the zeros (if any) on the right will become nines.

```
9324930000000 - 1 = 9324929999999
```