# Why does n & (n - 1) always clear 1 bit from n?

Tags: bit-manipulation

Given a number `n`, the bit wise operation `n & (n - 1)` always produces a number that is 1 bit away from `n`. Below are some examples:

```
n = 4 => b'100' & b'011' = b'000'
n = 5 => b'101' & b'100' = b'100'
n = 6 => b'110' & b'101' = b'100'
```

In other words, `n & (n - 1)` always clears 1 bit from `n`. Why is this? Can someone provide a proof?

Comment: Please [edit] your questions to include what you have tried so far? Where do you stuck in your proof?

Comment: there are a lot of duplicates: [Why does (x-1) toggle all the bits from the rightmost set bit of x?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50869508/995714), [n & (n-1) what does this expression do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4678333/995714), [How does this line work? n=n&(n-1)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15370250/995714), [What does the bitwise code “$n & ($n - 1)” do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1551500/995714)

Comment: Yes. I closed the thread.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this post as the linked threads doesn't exactly answer the question I proposed. The links provided answers the questions "what does n & (n-1) do?" And all of the answers says "it tests whether if n is a power of 2". My question is asking "why n & (n-1) clears 1 bit from n". An answer to this doesn't exactly follow from knowing whether if n is a power of 2.

Comment: this question [How does this line work ? n=n&(n-1)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15370410/995714) already states that why the last 1 bit is cleared. It doesn't say anything about power of 2 (to check that you need another comparison with 0)

Comment: [what is the means of i &=(i-1)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38644840/995714)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some preliminary remarks:

- The statement is true for when *n* is non-zero. There must be at least one 1-bit.
- A bitwise AND-operation copies the bits that are *the same* in both operands (`1&1==1` and `0&0==0`), and produces a zero bit when the corresponding bits are *different* (`1&0==0` and `0&1==0`).

Subtraction of 1 is easy when *n* is odd: you just clear that final 1-bit and you're done. When *n* is not odd, you need to "borrow" from an adjacent bit, which leads to a potential cascade of borrowing, until you find a 1-bit you can borrow from (See American method for manual subtraction on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtraction#American_method)). This means that starting from the right (at the least significant bit of *n*), you flip bits one by one, until the first 1-bit is encountered, which is also flipped.

So in a subtraction you flip a group of bits which includes exactly *one* 1-bit, which by consequence is the only one that gets flipped to a 0-bit.

As the bit-wise AND-operation on *n* will produce a 0 for every bit that was flipped for getting *n-1*, but will keep any other bit of *n* as it was before, it actually clears *one* 1-bit of *n*.

From this follows also that the bit that is cleared, is always the least significant 1-bit in *n*.

Comment: Ah that makes intuitive sense. Thank you